# CodeIgniter relative links without base_url()

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, base-url

My site is on "localhost/mysite" but when I view it on the browser, layout and links are broken. CSS and JS files are on "localhost/mysite/themes/" but this is what I see in the source code:

```
<link href="/themes/new/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/themes/new/js/scroll.js"></script>
```

And when I click on the links above, I always get to the following addresses and they are broken:

```
http://localhost/themes/new/css/style.css
http://localhost/themes/new/js/scroll.js
```

"mysite" path is already missing. It should be:

```
http://localhost/mysite/themes/new/css/style.css
http://localhost/mysite/themes/new/js/scroll.js
```

On htdocs\mysite\application\application\config\config.php, I have this setting and it should be left unedited.

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

On htdocs\mysite.htaccess, I have this setting, and it's probably the file that needs changes.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I looked around and tried all the suggestions by changing .htaccess but nothing really helped to make it work. It's funny when I change

```
href="/themes/new/css/style.css
```

to

```
href="".base_url()."themes/new/css/style.css"
```

everything works perfectly. But this is not the solution. It's a big site and I shouldn't be editing too much files by adding base_url() function, etc. Maybe we can do something on .htaccess? :(

Comment: try $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/mysite/';

Comment: It won't work either.

Comment: check the permission for 'themes/new/css' and 'themes/new/js/'

Comment: I have no problem with the permission. I just wonder why I get to localhost/themes/css/ when I click on the link. Why not localhost/mysite/themes/new/css? Hmmm...

Comment: This is happening because the link is root relative, with "localhost" being the root, if you create a virtual server and add an entry to your hosts file, you can fake a real site and this would work fine. of course you can just use `base_url('path/to/files.css')` and everything will work too

Comment: Creating a virtual server is something I have not done yet. I will appreciate it if you can tell me how it is done. :)

Comment: @KarlSJ I have to go out for an interview! If I remember I will pop back on and help. In the meantime google is your friend :) "How to set up a virtual server"

Comment: @karlSJ After thinking about this for a while I would totally recommend using base_url as you can pick up the code, dump it on a new server and CodeIgniter will make sure (or try it's best) to keep everything working as expected, so in essence, use `base_url('/path/to/file.js')` regardless of whether your on a proper host setup or not

Comment: Thanks to Dale for suggesting me to create a virtual host. It works perfectly on localhost now, but my problem is how to make it work on a domain called domain.com/mysite. I can't add base_url() function. It's  too much work for 5 thousand files. :D